# Project still uses old Chrome webdriver even after I installed a later version

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I wanted to run a demo code -FaceboookCodedUITestProject- and I see that it doesnt run on chrome browser, gives this error on console ,even though it starts a chrome

```
 Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923
 only local connections are allowed
```

I search and found this issue comes with some version so I installed Selenium.WebDriver.3.141.0 with nuget and I can see when I click on webDriver folder in preferences , however I still get same error on console and it says Satrting ChromeDrive 2.25. How can I remove ChromeDriver 2.25 and use only 3.141 ?

C:\Users\rasim.avci\source\repos\FaceboookCodedUITestProject\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.3.141.0\lib\net45\WebDriver.dll

Comment: The code you are running is likely referencing the path to the old driver. Post the relevant code that instantiates the driver.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome driver is different from Nuget package library.

1. ChromeDriver(2.25) is a standalone selenium webdriver which interacts with chrome browser. The 2.25 version is not compatible with latest version of chrome
2. And Nuget package is selenium library to write the test. It should not be confused with driver

To fix this, find where chromedriver.exe is! .

- Open CMD prompt and type Chromedriver. If it runs successfully, then chromedriver would have been added in Environment PATH and its easy to get the location from there

Comment: So you mean I should first install a newwer version of chromedriver and then I need to change envrinment path to the new installation of chromeDriver ?

Comment: I get ChromeDriver 2.45 and double click it, it gives same error for ChromeDriver 2.45, what should I do ? Btw its not an installation file but executable, just opens same console as is I run rom Visual Studio.

Comment: From another source I found selenium-chrome-driver-3.0.1.jar, where should I put it ? will it change ChromeDriver also ?

Comment: I tried to connect local IP instead of facebook but this time I get different error. A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:2733/session/2de362f059cc7adda34240e499b47597/title. The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the message was: blah blah

Comment: Chromedriver can be installed using NuGet... along with drivers for all the other major browsers.